# SQLite and Mathematica

Tags: databaselink, sql

I want to connect to a local database with *Mathematica*. I used DB Browser for SQLite to create the database with a single table and then exported it locally as a .sql file. To access the database I tried the following lines:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"];
OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite"]]
db = Database`OpenDatabase["C:\\db\\testDB.sql"];
results = Database`QueryDatabase[db, "SELECT * FROM `Table1`"]
```

The following error is output:

```
 Database`QueryDatabase::stmt: The statement "SELECT * FROM `Table1`" is invalid: "file is encrypted or is not a database".
```

The testDB.sql file looks like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE "Table1" (
    `field1`    TEXT,
    `field2`    TEXT,
);
INSERT INTO `Table1` VALUES ('point1','point2');
INSERT INTO `Table1` VALUES ('dot1','dot2');
COMMIT;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thx.

Comment: Your mathematica database functions (``Database`*``) deviate considerably from [what I am used to](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/guide/SQLDatabaseOperations.html).  The result of OpenSQLConnection needs to be assigned to a variable which will be used in future access to the database. I would do the 4th line with an SQLExecute. I believe the backticks shouldn't be in that line.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Perhaps he is referring to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26265/12) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61116/12)?

Comment: SQLite is also fundamentally different from other SQL engines, as it doesn't work in a client server configuration. Are you sure it can actually work with mathematica?

Comment: 2 cents: rarely use anything other than SQLExecute when working with SQL databases.

Comment: @Szabolcs ok, so it seems v10 should be able to do it. Must try it once.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch that's what I use mainly. I often construct SQL strings using mathematica code and feed the result to SQLexecute.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I just prefer it because you can use the same SQL requests as you would in a "normal" SQL interface. For me it makes everything more portable across applications.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries it was possible to work with SQLite databases since at least Mathematica 8. Also, related: [61116](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61116/how-to-update-bundled-sqlite-library-or-driver-in-v10-for-os-x)

Comment: @shrx Yeah, I already read the stuff at that link and so discovered that v10 has SQLite as part of the delivery. Have been trying it a bit, though I'm mainly working with MS SQL Server. Not aware of SQlite being present since 8, and as far as I recall the sql information functions didn't report that eiter.

Comment: From your question I guess you are somewhat disturbed from the fact that there are two completely independent ways to access SQLite from Mathematica, so maybe [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73438/169) is also of interest. One thing that I'd use with care in Mathematica strings is the backquotes: these do have special meanings in e.g. `StringForm` and similar functionality could potentially interfere with their use in SQL code, so I'd probably avoid them if not needed, I typically get along with single quotes in SQL...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`` DatabaseLink` `` and the `` Database` `` functions are actually two completely independent ways to access databases. The `` Database` `` functions are a direct and undocumented way to access SQLite databases only. It was available for version 7 to 11.0 but does not exist anymore in version 11.1. It had the advantage of being very fast to open a connection (compared to `` DatabaseLink` ``) but is undocumented and had some issues with non-ascii strings. There are various differences between the `` Database` `` and the `` DatabaseLink` `` functions in how the results are returned (and errors handled). As `` DatabaseLink` `` did not bring an SQLite driver until one of the 10.x versions, for versions 7 to 9 the `` Database` `` functions were an easy way to access SQLite databases out of the box. You could install a JDBC driver for SQLite in older versions to access a SQLite database via `` DatabaseLink` `` as well.

If using the undocumented `` Database` `` functions with one of the mathematica versions that have them, there is no reason to `` Needs["DatabaseLink`"] ``. The following should work without any `Needs` in a fresh kernel with versions 7 to 11.0:

```
 db = Database`OpenDatabase["C:/db/testDB.sql"];
 Database`QueryDatabase[db, "SELECT * FROM `Table1`;"]
```

Since at least version 10.3 there is a SQLite driver coming with `` DatabaseLink` `` so that seems to be the recommended way to access a SQLite database for newer versions. Especially if using version 11.1 (and presumably newer) where the `` Database` `` functions have been removed you would instead need to use:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
db = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite","C:/db/testDB.sql"]]
SQLExecute[db,"SELECT * FROM `Table1`;"]
```

Comment: ``Database` `` functions are not present in 12.0. I cannot find where they moved to.

Comment: Never mind, there is some published stuff: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DatabaseConnect.html

Comment: As mentioned in the post the ``Database` `` have been removed in 11.1. The new functionality around `RelationalDatabase` and `Entities` as a third, newer and AFAIK independent way to access databases...

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Szabolcs. Based on the content of the 2nd link that you posted, I realized that the code is not expected to work for *Mathematica* v.9 (command JDBC is not known). In any case, I was able to get the content of the database using the following lines:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"];
db = Database`OpenDatabase["C:/db/testDB.sql"];
Database`QueryDatabase[db, "SELECT * FROM `Table1`;"]
```

Comment: I think you won't need ```Needs["DatabaseLink`"]``` when you use the ```Database`*``` functions. These undocumented functions are completely unrelated to the DatabaseLink functionality AFAIK.